# Is there a way to make a score counter where a level ends at a certain score but can continue past that same score in further levels of the game?

Tags: python

I have a simple mathematics game that works fine. Currently, it ends each section of the game (i.e. Addition level, Multiplication level, etc) when the user answers correctly until a score of 5 is reached.

My problem is that when the user wants to play a different section within the same playthrough, the game will end after the first correct answer because the score is still at 5. I want to make it so the user has to achieve 5 correct answers every time the user chooses to play a new section while still having a score counter going beyond 5.

Each section has basically the same code.

````
    import time
    import random
    from subprocess import call


    def menuScreen():
        ```


    def addition():
        ```


    def multiplication():
        time.sleep(float(1.5))
        print("I see you like multiplication, It's my favourite!" + "\n" + "You're not gonna like this game tho.")
        time.sleep(2)
        Random = 1
        Random_two = 2
        lit = (Random + Random_two)
        answer = str(lit)
        global score
        while answer == str(lit):
            for x in range(1):
                Random = random.randint(1, 11)
                Random_two = random.randint(1, 11)
            lit = (Random * Random_two)
            answer = str(lit)
            print("What is " + str(Random) + " x " + str(Random_two) + "?")
            userInput = input()
            if userInput == (str(lit)):
                if score == 5:
                    print("Congratulations! You win.")
                    print("Do you want to know your score?")
                    userInput = input()
                    myList = ["okay", "Okay", "sure", "Sure", "ye", "Ye", "yes", "Yes"]
                    if userInput in myList:
                        print("Your score = " + str(score))
                        menuScreen()
                    else:
                        print("Okay, Goodbye.")
                        menuScreen()
                    break
                print("Next question.")
                answer = str(lit)
                score += 1
            else:
                print("Yikes, better luck next time")
                menuScreen()


    def subtraction():
       ```


    def division():
        ```

    score = 0
    menuScreen()
````

If my explanation is confusing, just comment and I can clarify. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply have some kind of global variable `wins = 0` and then modify your score check to be

```
if score == (wins+1)*5
```

Edit: as requested, a small working example of my suggestion:

```py
import time

score = 0
wins = 0


def multiplication():
    global score, wins
    print("Let's multipy! Wins =", wins)
    while score < (wins + 1) * 5:
        score += 1
        print("Multiplying! Score =", score)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    wins += 1

multiplication()
multiplication()
```

Comment: I just tried this and got the same results. I am most likely not implementing it correctly, do you have an example to show me by chance?